# Getting exception while trying to execute my project? "There was an error in the forked process"

Tags: jenkins, testng, pom.xml

I've got this error:

> Cannot find class in classpath:com.qa.Testcases.CreateAdminTest
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: There
>   was an error in the forked process
>
> at
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:658)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:533)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:278)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:244)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1194)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1022)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:868)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:154)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:146)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
>     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:309)   at
>   org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:194)    at
>   org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:107)  at
>   org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven35Launcher.main(Maven35Launcher.java:130)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if .class file present in your project.

This must be your class file :`com.qa.Testcases.CreateAdminTest`